# While loop program doesn't function properly

Tags: java, eclipse, loops

My while loop seems to have a problem which i can't find. When i run the program it shows that it runs but nothing happens. Help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Excersice8 {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        String answer = null;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (!"Done".equals(answer));
        {
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
            answer = input.nextLine();
            if (!"Done".equals(answer)) {
                System.out.println("Enter the value");
                char ch1 = input.next().charAt(0);
                System.out.println();
                if ((ch1 >= '0' && ch1 <= '9'))
                    System.out.println("Number ");
                else if ((ch1 >= 'a' && ch1 <= 'z'))
                    System.out.println("Small Character");
                else if ((ch1 >= 'A' && ch1 <= 'Z'))
                    System.out.println("Capital Character");
                else
                    System.out.println("Symbol");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Thank you");
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo: You have an infinite loop, because you put a semicolon after `while (!"Done".equals(answer))`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon from the end of the line in

```
while (!"Done".equals(answer));
```

The semicolon is an empty statement in itself, which became the body of your while loop. The block in curly braces after it was no longer part of your while loop as a result.

Using automatic formatting/indenting in an IDE would have shown you the problem; it would have put the semicolon on the next line with an indent.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and along with the aforementioned issue with the colon at the end of the line: `while (!"Done".equals(answer));` Your code for stopping the program using the word "Done" doesn't work as intended.

Each time you were checking for the "done" word twice, despite only needing to check for it once.

```
    System.out.println("Enter the value: (Type 'done' to stop)");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = input.next();

    while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
        char ch1 = answer.charAt(0);
        if ((ch1 >= '0' && ch1 <= '9'))
            System.out.println("Number");
        else if ((ch1 >= 'a' && ch1 <= 'z'))
            System.out.println("Small Character");
        else if ((ch1 >= 'A' && ch1 <= 'Z'))
            System.out.println("Capital Character");
        else
            System.out.println("Symbol");

        System.out.println("Enter the value: (Type 'done' to stop)");
        answer = input.next();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the empty statement in the while loop, you are using `nextLine()` and `next()` together. A call to `next()` doesn't consume the line break in the end of the line and that causes the following `nextLine()` to only read the line break. You won't be able to stop the loop unless you read each line the same way.